My institution only counts two publications in the same journal for promotion; I have four. Can I retract them and republish somewhere else?
My institution's policy is to consider a maximum of two articles published in the same journal for promotion appraisal.
I published four independent articles at different times in the same journal. The Committee for promotions only considered two of them based on the policy.
Can I retract the other two and publish them in another journal? There is nothing wrong with the articles in terms of quality or content.

Why did you do that, knowing the policy?

Too many Nature cover articles! No tenure for you!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

By promotion, do you mean moving up the academic ladder, or do you mean promotion in their marketing material (website, news articles, etc)?

So confused! Reaction is considered as a serious bad record for a researcher. You don't want it, trust me

The journals I'm familiar with do not like issuing retractions, and reserve them for cases with substantial scientific errors, misconduct, improper ethics approval, and the like. See the COPE Guidelines for the types of criteria editors use to decide on whether retraction is warranted. Notably, your wanting to republish the papers elsewhere so they'd count differently in your performance review would not be sufficient reason. In addition, be careful what you wish for. Given that retractions are predominantly issued for such negative reasons, it is preferable to not have retractions to one's name. And the same silly institutional policy you are worried about might well count them negatively...
What to do going forward depends a lot on the time frames involved. Perhaps you can eat this mistake and spread your publications more broadly in the future. Perhaps it's too late for that, and you'll have to look for another institution. In that case, it is likely much better to not have retractions.

Indeed. The only way that the OP's question makes sense is if they do not at all appreciate how serious of an action retracting a published article is, thinking of it instead as some sort of minor clerical step.

Notably, your wanting to republish the papers elsewhere so they'd count differently in your performance review would not be sufficient reason. - In addition, any reputable journal isn't going to want to publish a paper that has been retracted from somewhere else.

@Kimball I didn't go into that because I think it's not quite so cut and dry - republishing retracted articles actually seems to happen every now and then, at least in some fields, including in reasonable journals (but maybe not the top ones?). The linked COPE guidelines note that this can be done "if not all of the content was found to be unreliable" and if done transparently. That said, I'm not sure any reputable journal would be interested doing so for frivolous retractions, potentially opening themselves up to the same treatment in the future.

It is not clear to me that a (reputable) journal would be willing to publish a paper that has already been published, and then retracted, elsewhere. This fact is likely to be detected when the journal runs their anti-plagiarism checks, as your original manuscript will probably be in their database. To avoid this creating problems, you would need to declare up-front that you had previously published the paper and then retracted it.
Any editor seeing this unusual behaviour is going to be concerned: why are you doing this? No doubt you would explain that it's because of your institution's rules, but the editor might wonder whether that's the complete story. "Are there other problems with the paper that are going to emerge if I accept this? Perhaps it's best if we just say 'no'."
In addition, note that your paper would need to undergo a full review process in any new journal, and there is no guarantee that the reviews would be straightforward.

Also OP's institution might have something to object: this ruse could be seen as an attempt to circumvent their policy.

One of the very few legitimate ways to republish an already published paper is translations. It used to be common for Russian mathematicians to publish articles in Russian in Russian journals, which where then translated and republished for "the West".
If your institution is based in a non-English speaking country, there might be local-language journals that would consider publishing a translation of your previous articles. This is way more likely if the subject is something that might be of particular interest to locals. If you have transfered the copyright to the publisher of the original articles, you would also need permission from them.
Of course, your local rules also might only count international journals.

In fact, since late 1930s (and until the end of the USSR) it was a requirement that before an article by a Soviet scientist was published abroad, it has to be published in USSR.

This is a clever idea. Even if you're not based in a non-English speaking country, there's nothing stopping you from working with a translator to publish translations of your articles, assuming you can find a journal which would accept them.

So much better an idea than a retraction!

You could hire a freelancer from one of the many websites to translate them professionally for you, if you are unable to translate them yourself.

Aside from copyright issues (maybe side-step by rebranding as an analysis of the original paper, with some scattered perfunctory words thrown in here and there for the analysis), this answer might cause a cottage industry of such journals. We've already had Antarctica Journal of Mathematics, so why not something like Ganymede Journal of Mathematics published in Esperanto? (Machine translations to  Esperanto accepted.)

@MoisheKohan A requirement of who? The USSR? The journals?

@AzorAhai-him-: Soviet authorities. There were two, somewhat conflicting, explanations for this policy: (1) Soviet patriotism, (2) prevention of leaking of state secrets. Furthermore, one could not just send a paper to a foreign journal, it had to be done through "proper channels" (after vetting by a "security department").

@DaveLRenfro I see nothing wrong with (translated) articles published in Esperanto – there is a community of Esperanto speakers (on Earth, not on Ganymede) which prefer to read articles in Esperanto compared to English. Though these translations of course should not count in addition to the originals for the policy here, and you'd likely want to still have some peer review for it to count at all.

Absolutely NO. You don't retract papers to publish them elsewhere. It's much easier to change the institution to another one with more reasonable rules.

Can I retract these papers and republish them?
No.  No no no no.  You can't do this.  No.
Journals generally only ever retract papers for serious problems, such as major errors in the papers or academic misconduct on the part of the authors.  Retracting a paper because you submitted it to the "wrong" journal does not rise to that level.  That's on you.
Moreover, when you agree to have a paper published in a journal, you are typically required to provide that journal with some kind of exclusive license  to publish that paper.  This means that you cannot submit it to another journal—publication rights remain with the journal in which it is first published (there are generally carve-outs for posting a copy of the paper on a personal website or on a preprint server, but that journal gets to be the only journal in which your paper is officially published).
And, even then, supposing that you were able to retract the papers, no other reputable journal would publish them.  Once a paper is retracted, it should probably be seen as dead.  It looks very suspicious to most people if you retract a paper, then re-publish it elsewhere—whether true or not, it looks like something sneaking, underhanded, and suspicious is going on.
Given the state of the world, there is very little that you can do with those papers now.  You need to write new papers, and submit them to a more diverse catalog of journals.  I would suggest doing that as quickly as possible, and get over the sunk costs of having published four papers in one journal.
Read the syllabus.
When you take a job, or are looking for promotion, you need to read the syllabus.  That is, you need to look at the requirements for the job or for promotion, and make sure that you understand the rules, and that you are following them.
Your institution has a rule:  only two papers from any one journal will be counted towards promotion.
You should have known about that rule before you started working towards promotion, and should have had plenty of time to build up the diverse portfolio of publications your institution requires.  Note that I am not making any judgement about whether or not this is a good rule—that is irrelevant.  It is your institution's rule, and you need to follow it.[1]
The moral of the story is that, like a student taking a class, you need to read the syllabus.

[1] As an example of a stupid rule that I have to follow:  a condition of my employment is that I swear/affirm an oath which states that I will protect the Constitution and the State of Arizona from all enemies, foreign and domestic.  It is dumb, but I have to do it if I want to get paid.

I totally don't understand why anyone would want to maximize the number of journals you publish in. Say, if you have 4 papers published in Science, why would anyone prefer that two of them were published in some "Journal of Irrelevant Results" instead? What's the point?

@Vosoni I made no comment about whether or not this is a good or reasonable practice.  Personally, I think it is kind of optimizing for the wrong thing (I understand why such a policy might exist, but you point out an edge case in which it gives the wrong result).  The point is that it is the rule that the asker's institution has.  If you care about your career, you follow the rules, however stupid they are.  Once you have tenure, you can try to change the rules, or move somewhere else.

That being said, I highly doubt that the original asker has four publications in an A+ journal, and that likely isn't the edge case that this policy is designed to put a stop to. Rather, I would imagine that the policy exists to prevent a person from using four publications in "Journal of Irrelevant Results" (which is edited by their good buddy) in order to advance their career.  This publication-counting is a dumb way of promoting people, but I can see the reasoning behind it.

Putting a threshold on the impact factor or just counting Q1 journals would certainly work better.

If you care about your career, you follow the rules, however stupid they are. Questionable logic. I would try to change the rules or quit the institution with such unreasonable rules, if I care about my career. You follow the rules only if you don't care about your career and just want to flow with the current.

@Vosoni That is terrible advice for someone who is early in their career.  The academic job market is not very friendly right now.  It is generally not wise to make waves in your early career, and it is not always possible to just find a new job.  Once you are established, yes!  work to change the rules.  But a lot of early-career academics are already in a tenuous place.

I think quite the opposite. At the moment when you are about to be promoted is the best time to collect more job offers and choose the best. Say, right after you completed your PhD it is normal (and recommended) to search for a postdoc elsewhere and not just wait that your old institution "promotes" you to a postdoc. Same with tenure. Someone with just 4 publications is likely to be at an early postdoc stage, that is ideal time to seek a better place. Right after getting a new job quitting and going elsewhere would look suspicious and also there is much less motivation to do so.

@Vosoni These things almost always get pushed from the top: government agencies, so the ask is to go move to a different country. That's far easier said than done.

@Vosoni Frankly, the advice you give seems terribly naive.  You seem to be saying "If you don't like something about the way that your organization works, you should just find another organization to work for!"  This is simply not feasible for most people in academia---ladder positions are few and far between, and increasingly being replaced by adjunct faculty.  Postdoc positions are highly competitive.  There just aren't a lot of options for someone who wants to remain in academia.

Moreover, the issue raised in this question is about one aspect of a job.  Maybe the asker really loves the geography of where they live, and have a great group of colleagues to work with.  Perhaps they have great compensation, wonderful health insurance, and a light teaching load.  There are many variables which contribute to quality of life, and having to have publications in multiple journals seems like a fairly inconsequential issue to storm out on (assuming that this is even possible for the asker). And, again, read the syllabus.  This requirement should not have come as a surprise.

@Vosoni: Say, right after you completed your PhD it is normal (and recommended) to search for a postdoc elsewhere and not just wait that your old institution "promotes" you to a postdoc. --- This sounds almost as strange as saying: "Right after you graduate high school, now is the time to search for a job, and not just wait for the school you attended to promote you to a teacher."
